# How does web application share signed cookie with AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-how-signed-cookies-work) has explained how to sign the cookie and set the cookie.

1. sign the cookie use the private key
2. set cookie
3. the browser of the user carries the cookie and tries to download the file.
4. CloudFront validates the cookie and responds to the request.

I have gone through several related questions.

1. [Stackoverflow: Setting Cookies for CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831580/setting-cookies-for-cloudfront)
2. [Stackoverflow: share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain#:%7E:text=But%20you%20CAN%27T%20set,a%20domain%20on%20a%20subdomain.)

Due to security, it seems not possible to share cookies between different subdomains.

Take this real-world scenario as an example:

- Web application's domain `www.example.com`
- AWS CloudFront distribution `file.example.com`

How does `www.example.com`(web application) set a signed cookie for `file.example.com`(CloudFront)?

Comment: Generally speaking `www.example.com` can issue cookies for both `www.example.com` and `example.com` - the `example.com` cookies will be sent along when requesting `file.example.com` or even `something.more.complex.example.com`.

Comment: a nice article to explain the approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990841/how-to-use-cloudfront-signed-cookies-in-the-browser

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990841/how-to-use-cloudfront-signed-cookies-in-the-browser